# GNU Make Pattern Rule on MacOS X

Tags: macos, build, makefile, gnu, gnu-make

I'm struggling with makefiles on OS X Lion. I'm trying to use % pattern rule to compile all my .c files into objects in current dir. I'm using rule:

```
%.o : %.c                                                                      
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

But make says that no targets. I know that % pattern it is feature of gMake but -v says that I've got GNU make installed. I've also tried old style:

```
 .cpp.o:
        gcc $^ -o $@
```

But it is do not working to. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try [gmake](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/gmake/Portfile) from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

Comment: Are your input files `.c` files or `.cpp` files?

Comment: My examples is just examples. In real I search for `.cc` files.  `%.o: %.cc                                                            $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@`

Comment: I've solve it. I tried to use patterns with vpath for build in separate folder. I've changed my folders structure to build in single folder and patters work well. I don't know why, I thought that it should work well with vpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's your entire Makefile, then indeed, it contains no targets. Invoke it with `make file.o` or add a phony target `all` which lists the names of the files you want to have built. It could be as simple as

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))
```

What you have are pattern rules which specify "if you want to build a target of type `*.o`, here's how to do that" but no actual targets which specify "this is a file we want to build".

By the by, GNU Make already knows how to compile C files, so you don't really need to define that, unless you have a specific need to override the built-in pattern rule.